# Symfony 6.2 php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle Producer Cannot autowire service

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

Есть проект на symfony v6.2 с установленным пакетом php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle. В нём настроен один Producer (PushToQueue) и один Consumer (Send). Когда я пытаюсь добавить ещё одну пару Producer(PushToQueueTest)-Consumer(SendTest) и использовать новый Producer(PushToQueueTest) в зависимостях любого класса, происходит ошибка автовнедрения зависимостей:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Email\Infrastructure\Service\PushToQueueTest": argument "$conn" of method "OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\BaseAmqp::__construct()" references class "PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this class to the existing "old_sound_rabbit_mq.connection.default" service.
```

При попытке внедрить зависимость $conn через config/services.yaml таким образом

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        bind:
            $conn: '@old_sound_rabbit_mq.connection.default'
```

я получаю новую проблему:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "name"
file: /app/vendor/php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle/RabbitMq/BaseAmqp.php,
line: 201
type: ErrorException
```

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.**

Ниже содержимое всех необходимых файлов.

config/packages/old_sound_rabbit_mq.yaml:

```yaml
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        default:
            host: 'rabbitmq'
            port: '%env(resolve:RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PORT)%'
            user: '%env(resolve:RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER)%'
            password: '%env(resolve:RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS)%'
            vhost: '/'
            lazy: true
            connection_timeout: 3
            read_write_timeout: 3
            keepalive: false
            heartbeat: 0
            use_socket: true
    producers:
        send_email:
            class: App\Email\Infrastructure\Service\PushToQueue
            connection: default
            exchange_options: { name: 'send_email', type: direct }
        send_email_test:
            class: App\Email\Infrastructure\Service\PushToQueueTest
            connection: default
            exchange_options: { name: 'send_email_test', type: direct }
    consumers:
        send_email:
            connection: default
            exchange_options: { name: 'send_email', type: direct }
            queue_options: { name: 'send_email' }
            callback: App\Email\Application\Consumer\Send
        send_email_test:
            connection: default
            exchange_options: { name: 'send_email_test', type: direct }
            queue_options: { name: 'send_email_test' }
            callback: App\Email\Application\Consumer\Send
```

PushToQueue:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Email\Infrastructure\Service;

use App\Shared\Infrastructure\Service as SharedInfrastructureService;

class PushToQueue extends SharedInfrastructureService\BasePushToQueue
{
}
```

PushToQueueTest:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Email\Infrastructure\Service;

use App\Shared\Infrastructure\Service as SharedInfrastructureService;

class PushToQueueTest extends SharedInfrastructureService\BasePushToQueue
{
}
```

Send:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Email\Application\Consumer;

use OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ConsumerInterface;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
use App\Email\Domain\Service as DomainService;

class Send implements ConsumerInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        readonly private DomainService\Send $sendService,
    ) {
    }

    public function execute(AMQPMessage $msg): int
    {
        $data = json_decode($msg->getBody(), true);
        $status = $this->sendService->setData($data)->service();
        return $status->value;
    }
}
```

SendTest:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Email\Application\Consumer;

use OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ConsumerInterface;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
use App\Email\Domain\Service as DomainService;

class SendTest implements ConsumerInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        readonly private DomainService\Send $sendService,
    ) {
    }

    public function execute(AMQPMessage $msg): int
    {
        $data = json_decode($msg->getBody(), true);
        $status = $this->sendService->setData($data)->service();
        return $status->value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам задал вопрос, сам и отвечу, потому что решил проблему.

Я заметил, что переименование настроенного корректно продюсера в конфигурации config/packages/old_sound_rabbit_mq.yaml приводит к возникновению той же ошибки.

Проблема заключалась в названии переменной продюсера. В моём случае она называлась

```php
PushToQueue $sendEmailProducer
```

Когда я изменял название продюсера в конфигурации на send_email_test, необходимо было также изменить название переменной на $sendEmailTestProducer. Даже не смотря на то, что я явно указывал тип переменной, а не ProducerInterface.

Прочитать об этом из первоисточника можно здесь: https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle#autowiring-producers-and-consumers